# Bitbucket Pipeline - Docker memory

Tags: docker, memory, bitbucket-pipelines

I have two different pipeline steps each requiring a different amount of memory. One needs 4096 (size: 2x) memory which has been defined but the other step needs significantly less memory. Is there any way to define the memory for each of the steps in order to not waste pipeline minutes?

Answer (score 3):

Size can be configured for every step.
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/